# Rmd/knitr How to use a PDF LaTeX template that works

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, pandoc

## The Problem

I am knitting Rmd files to PDFs. I need to customize the title page (add another subtitle somwhere, add several logos, ...). This seems to go beyond what the YAML header is supposed to provide.

So, I thought it'd be a good idea to modify the default latex template to suit my needs. What I want is to add, e.g., `subtitle2` to my YAML header and have the template pick it up and render it in the correct position.
Shouldn't be too difficult, just look up the default template and modify it. (Let's hope that the metadata will *just* be available there, and I don't have to touch more than this.)

To my suprise, I didn't have `pandoc` installed. But the knitting in RStudio revealed that it uses a bundled pandoc (in `/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc`). Running this (`with -v`) reveals that it's version 3.1.something. I then went to GitHub and downloaded the `default.latex` for the [corresponding tag.](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/3.1.1/data/templates/default.latex), and tried to knit the same Rmd with the otherwise untouched `default.latex`:

```yaml
output:
  pdf_document:
    template: ./my-template.latex
```

Sadly, this throws an error like `Missing number, treated as zero` plus some `w` and a `l.91`, which I assume is a line number, but it does neither correspond to the template nor the generated tex file (nor the Rmd).

## Questions

- Is my approach sane? Or am I missing some *easier* way to have a customized title page from the YAML header (I know, I could drop it altogether and recreate it in the body).
- What's the default template used when I knit via RStudio? I cannot find a `default.latex` anywhere on my drive and I don't see similar templates anywhere within the RStudio files.
- How could I reasonably debug what the error is? The message is super useless.
- Now if I wanted this to work in different environments, possibly with different pandoc versions, this would probably break. Is it just a stupid approach? Should I just drop the YAML header and do everything by myself? I'd be surprised if the authors hadn't thought of customization options - the [custom template](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/ioslides-presentation.html#custom-templates-2) is mentioned in many places.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/svmiller/stevetemplates for examples of custom templates.

Comment: @user2554330 looks helpful, I'll perhaps sit down and work through some of them to try to answer my own question